# Not able to connect node with hub in selenium grid 4.2.2

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, selenium-grid

I am trying to use selenium grid 4.2.2 I am creating a hub on the server and trying to create a node in the local machine but when  I am trying to make the connection between the hub and node connection **I am getting an error sending registration event again and again(local machine and server are in the same network)**

hub:

> java -jar selenium-server-4.2.2.jar hub

node:
java -jar selenium-server-4.2.2.jar node --detect-drivers true --publish-events tcp://{hubIP}:4442 --subscribe-events tcp://{hubIP}:4443

please check the attachment in that hub is successfully created even though I cannot create a node in the local machine I don't know why??please help me reading to this thank you in advanced(all Brwoser driver present in selenium grid folder )

[image]